# Elqouent Javascript Exercise "nth"

Tags: javascript

I have the following code for the nth function in the Chapter 4 exercises in Eloquent JavaScript:

```
function nth(list, num){
   var node = list;
   if(num === 0) {
     return node.value;
   } else {
      if (node.rest) {
         node = node.rest;
         nth(node, num - 1);
      } else {
         return undefined;
      }
   }
}

console.log(nth(arrayToList([10,20,30]),1));
// -> 20
```

I have an iterative version of the function that works as expected; however, this recursive version of the function returns undefined even though a call to console.log right before the return statement correctly prints node.value. Why?

Here is the arrayToList function as well:

```
function arrayToList(arr){
   var list = {value: arr[arr.length - 1], rest: null};
   for (var i = arr.length - 2; i >=0; i--){
      list = {value: arr[i], rest: list};
   }
   return list;
}
```

Comment: You're missing `return` on the recursive call. If you don't return what the recursive call returns, the result will be `undefined`.

Comment: `return nth(node, num - 1);`

Comment: Because you never do `return nth(node, num - 1);` so the function executes `nth(...)` and then never returns the result of that function. Always define explicit return values everywhere.

Comment: an alternative: `var arrayToList = arr => arr.reduceRight((rest, value) => ({value, rest}), null);` and `var nth = (list, num) => list /* && num >= 0*/? num? nth(list.rest, num-1): list.value: void 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the recursively obtained result:

```
return nth(node, num - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it